# What is the grammatical function of "for" in "For it breaches countless generations of human social arrangements"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions

> Yet it is amazing that this deal works at all – however imperfectly. **For** it breaches countless generations of human social arrangements.
>   <sub>––*Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind*, by Yuval Noah Harari, pg. 359-60</sub>
>   <sup>(via: http://www.words-and-dirt.com/words/quote-10-30-2015/)</sup>

What grammatical function does "for" in the sentence have?
And I'm not sure what the last sentence is talking about also.

Comment: Read this *for* as "because" and you should understand it all right. BTW, you might've already known this song: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_He%27s_a_Jolly_Good_Fellow. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[For](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for)*** -conjunction -  (old-fashioned or literary)

​

> - because; as:
>
>   - *She remained silent, for her heart was heavy and her spirits low.*

Cambridge Dictionary